# Custom loading graphic for Android - control an animated gif?

Tags: android, loading, animated-gif

I want to create a custom, complicated loading graphic for my Android App (minSDK 8).

If I create a GIF with 100 frames, is there a way in Java/Android to tell it which frame to go to during my `'doProgress()'` function?

Is there another or better way to do custom loading graphics?

Answer (score 2):

> If I create a GIF with 100 frames, is there a way in Java/Android to tell it which frame to go to during my 'doProgress()' function?

Since Android does not do animated GIFs, no.

> Is there another or better way to do custom loading graphics?

Option #1: Use a [frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame).

Option #2: Use a `RotateAnimation` with a single image in an `ImageView`.

Option #3: Use `ViewPropertyAnimator` (using NineOldAndroids for the backport) to animate `android:rotation` with a single image in an `ImageView`.

There may be other options as well, though those are the three that come to mind.

Comment: Frame Animations are really simple to execute, and you end up with smooth results. So I +1 the first option.

Comment: I need to animate more than a simple rotation - sounds like #1 would be good, but I don't see how I can control which frame it's on specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gif image, then you can use `WebView` component to show the gif image. In webview, the image loops itself, we do not need to do extra work.